# How to obtain covariance matrix for constrained regression fit?

Tags: regression, covariance

**Is there an easy way to obtain the covariance of the parameters from a constrained regression fit?**

I am using the PCLS function in the MGCV package in R to fit the constrained regression, however I am open to other approaches.
The constraint I am imposing is that the coefficients must be positive.

Comment: How large is your sample?

Comment: Aren't you concerned that a covariance matrix is unlikely to be a useful description of parameter uncertainty for any estimates at or close to the constraints?

Comment: The sample is around 500.  @whuber Yes that is a concern.  And since I know some estimates will be close to the constraints it may not even make sense to think of a covariance matrix.  However since the PCLS function does some sort of optimization procedure, you would think you could get the Hessian matrix, which would provide some info.

Comment: @whuber Under nonnegativity constraints I would calculate this covariance matrix on the bootstrap estimated coefficients that are nonzero only... Ie use betahat=bootout$t; betahat[betahat==0]=NA # ignore the zeros as they are at the constraint boundary; vcov=cov(betahat,use="pairwise.complete.obs"); SEs=sqrt(diag(vcov)) - this will be a better description of the estimated parameters under nonnegativity constraints. If you would simulate from this vcov matrix you just have to set negative values to zero then.

Comment: @Tom Thank you.  My concern was motivated by the thought that the covariance matrix may be a poor description of the sampling distribution altogether, due to the boundary constraint.  Perhaps, then, a better use of a bootstrap or other resampling procedure would be not to estimate the covariance matrix but to study the distribution of the parameter estimates directly.

Comment: @whuber Yes but I was just checking this and if you look at the bootstrapped coefficients of a nonnegative least squares you'll see that the distribution of the parameters near the boundary are like mixture distributions with a point mass at zero (at the constraint boundary) but the rest of the distribution looking fairly normal/gaussian (similar to a Tweedie distribution). Hence, if your aim is to test whether your coefficients are sign greater than zero you can calculate the mean probability that your bootstrapped coefficients are zero...

Comment: @whuber  ...or you can calculate the SD of your strictly positive bootstrapped coefficients and do a one-sided t test based on that. Likewise, the latter recipe would be equivalent to what I wrote if you would like to get the full covariance matrix. You can use it to simulate new data around the nnls estimates just by setting negative values to zero. I just checked and the two methods (percentile method vs vcov matrix from nonneg coefficients) give almost the same result in practise.

Comment: I would also like to note that if you just want to fit nonnegative least squares that the nnls function is faster than PCLS / quadratic programming based fitting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first I would go with very simple bootstrap.

Basically something as follows:

1. Create a new data-set by resampling pairs of $(x,y)$.
2. Run your regression on this new data set and you will get some parameters $\hat \beta$.
3. Repeat 1 and 2 as many times as possible. Now you will have a large sets of $ \hat \beta$
4. Now just take the sample covariance of your $\hat \beta$.
5. Done

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Can you elaborate a bit of step 1 though? Re-sample with replacement? Or...?

Comment: Yes. Vanilla bootstrap is sampling with replacement. so for example if your data is $(x,y) = \{(1,1);(1,2);(1,3)\}$ a new data set would be $(1,3);(1,3);(1,1)$. This is not the only kind of resampling possible of course. Another one is to reuse all the $X$ and shocking all $Y$ by a noise. But pair resampling is the simplest and most agnostic

Comment: I read a lot on bootstrap but I never heard the term vanilla bootstrap. Maybe it is equivalent to what is called the ordinary or naive bootstrap.  As far as bootstrap pairs vs bootstrapping residuals, bootstrapping pairs is simpler but what do you mean by agnostic (not heavily model-dependent?)?

Comment: @MichaelChernick: [*Vanilla*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plain-vanilla) is a colloquial term for the "regular", "usual", or "simple" version of something.

Comment: @cardinal  I know that.  i just have never seen it used to describe the bootstrap before. Also agnostic means neither believing or disbelieving.  So I imagine that pertains to the model.  Bootstrapping pairs is less sensitive to model assumptions so it is agnostic toward the model I guess.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: I am not sure how much of a *regional* colloquialism that use of *vanilla* might be. (I figured you'd likely have heard it.) At any rate, what I meant (but didn't say very clearly) is that I'm almost positive CarrKnight was not using the term in some *bootstrap-specific* way. :)

Comment: Wow, sorry. Won't use that term again. Yes "vanilla" here was just to say "plain", "usual","ordinary". Not to connote any special bootstrap. Also, yes agnostic as in model agnostic. As in: I don't need to assume a specific type of error or that my model is predicting very well.

Comment: I was just struck by the unusual use of Vanilla> I do not object to the use of it in the context of the bootstrap any more than I would object to agnostic in terms of models.  These are just uncommon adjectives.

Comment: Under nonnegativity constraints I would calculate this covariance matrix on the bootstrap estimated coefficients that are nonzero though... Ie use betahat=bootout$t; betahat[betahat==0]=NA # ignore the zeros as they are at the constraint boundary; vcov=cov(betahat,use="pairwise.complete.obs"); SEs=sqrt(diag(vcov)) - this will be a better description of the estimated parameters under nonnegativity constraints. If you would simulate from this vcov matrix you just have to set negative values to zero then.